# How to wrap headers within a span from specific division using javascript

Tags: javascript, joomla

This is my actual code:

```
<div class="content">
<h3>This is test text</h3>
</div>
```

I want it like this:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="headers"><h3>This is test text</h3></div>
</div>
```

***N.B. I'm using Joomla!***

Comment: Your goal is invalid HTML, dont't do this, use `div` instead `span`, which is an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements).

Comment: Ok so how I will wrap my `h3` within a `div` with the class `headers`

Comment: why don't you use JQuery or mootools ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do the trick:

```
function insert_headers(my_class)
{
   //get your content element
   var contents = document.getElementsByClassName(my_class);
   //loop on the elements found
   for(var i=0;i<contents.length;i++)
   {
      var content = contents[i];
      //get the html content
      var html_content = content.innerHTML;
      //replace the h3 tags to insert the span ones
      html_content = html_content.replace('<h3>', '<div class="headers"><h3>');
      html_content = html_content.replace('</h3>', '</h3></div>');
      //set the html content back
      content.innerHTML = html_content;
   }
}
```

So if you have this:

```
<div class="content>
   <h3>This is test text</h3>
</div>
```

and you do this:

```
insert_headers('content');
```

you'll get this:

```
<div class="content>
   <div class="headers"><h3>This is test text</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, maybe you can tell me why? I need informations so I can help you. Did you put an ID in your content div? The function I provided works with IDs. If you want I cant re-write it for classes but maybe you could try like that first?

Comment: I would like to style my headers like this: [link](http://creativica.in/headers.jpg)

Comment: Still not working! :( Will this code work with Joomla? @PiTiNiNjA

Comment: This is a JS code, nothing unusual. I don't see why it wouldn't work with Joomla. Unless you provide error logs or something similar, I can't help you more.